# JAVA Multithreading Boolean vs AtomicBoolean

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to print from 1 to 10 using two different threads. I have created two classes implementing Runnable : OddPrinter and EvenPrinter which uses a shared Object for synchronisation so that only one thread prints at a time. I am using a isOddTurn variable to determine which thread's turn is to print the number to maintain the order. I am confused why using AtomicBoolean as type of isOdd variable works but not Boolean . The confusion is because the business logic is wrapped inside synchronized so race conditions shouldn't exist.

```
public class Test {

    private static Object object = new Object();
    private static AtomicBoolean isOddTurn = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    //private volatile Boolean isOddTurn = Boolean.TRUE;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.runDemo();
    }

    public void runDemo() {
        OddPrinter oddPrinter = new OddPrinter(isOddTurn, object);
        EvenPrinter evenPrinter = new EvenPrinter(isOddTurn, object);
        new Thread(oddPrinter).start();
        new Thread(evenPrinter).start();
    }

    class OddPrinter implements Runnable {

        private int counter = 1;

        private AtomicBoolean isOddTurn;

        private Object object;

        OddPrinter(AtomicBoolean isOddTurn, Object object) {
            this.isOddTurn = isOddTurn;
            this.object = object;
            System.out.println("Odd");
            System.out.println(this.isOddTurn.hashCode());
            System.out.println(isOddTurn.hashCode());
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (object) {
                while (counter <= 10) {
                    while (!isOddTurn.get()) {
                        try {
                            object.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(counter);
                    counter += 2;
                    isOddTurn.set(false);
                    object.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class EvenPrinter implements Runnable {

        private int counter = 2;

        private Object object;
        private AtomicBoolean isOddTurn;

        EvenPrinter(AtomicBoolean isOddTurn, Object object) {
            this.isOddTurn = isOddTurn;
            this.object = object;
            System.out.println("Evem");
            System.out.println(this.isOddTurn.hashCode());
            System.out.println(isOddTurn.hashCode());
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (object) {
                while (counter <= 10) {
                    while (isOddTurn.get()) {
                        try {
                            object.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(counter);
                    counter += 2;
                    isOddTurn.set(true);
                    object.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using isOddTurn of type volatile Boolean, it doesn't print 1 to 10 and gets stuck after printing 1

```
public class Test {

    private static Object object = new Object();
    //private static AtomicBoolean isOddTurn = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    private volatile Boolean isOddTurn = Boolean.TRUE;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.runDemo();
    }

    public void runDemo() {
        OddPrinter oddPrinter = new OddPrinter(isOddTurn, object);
        EvenPrinter evenPrinter = new EvenPrinter(isOddTurn, object);
        new Thread(oddPrinter).start();
        new Thread(evenPrinter).start();
    }

    class OddPrinter implements Runnable {

        private int counter = 1;

        private Boolean isOddTurn;

        private Object object;

        OddPrinter(Boolean isOddTurn, Object object) {
            this.isOddTurn = isOddTurn;
            this.object = object;
            System.out.println("Odd");
            System.out.println(this.isOddTurn.hashCode());
            System.out.println(isOddTurn.hashCode());
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (object) {
                while (counter <= 10) {
                    while (!isOddTurn) {
                        try {
                            object.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(counter);
                    counter += 2;
                    isOddTurn=Boolean.FALSE;
                    object.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class EvenPrinter implements Runnable {

        private int counter = 2;

        private Object object;
        private Boolean isOddTurn;

        EvenPrinter(Boolean isOddTurn, Object object) {
            this.isOddTurn = isOddTurn;
            this.object = object;
            System.out.println("Evem");
            System.out.println(this.isOddTurn.hashCode());
            System.out.println(isOddTurn.hashCode());
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (object) {
                while (counter <= 10) {
                    while (isOddTurn) {
                        try {
                            object.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(counter);
                    counter += 2;
                    isOddTurn=Boolean.TRUE;
                    object.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I make the isOddTurn variable as global Boolean instead of using it as instance variable in both threads, then it works fine.

```
public class Test {

    private static Object object = new Object();
    //private static AtomicBoolean isOddTurn = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    private Boolean isOddTurn = Boolean.TRUE;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.runDemo();
    }

    public void runDemo() {
        OddPrinter oddPrinter = new OddPrinter(object);
        EvenPrinter evenPrinter = new EvenPrinter(object);
        new Thread(oddPrinter).start();
        new Thread(evenPrinter).start();
    }

    class OddPrinter implements Runnable {

        private int counter = 1;


        private Object object;

        OddPrinter(Object object) {

            this.object = object;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (object) {
                while (counter <= 10) {
                    while (!isOddTurn) {
                        try {
                            object.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(counter);
                    counter += 2;
                    isOddTurn=Boolean.FALSE;
                    object.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class EvenPrinter implements Runnable {

        private int counter = 2;

        private Object object;


        EvenPrinter(Object object) {

            this.object = object;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (object) {
                while (counter <= 10) {
                    while (isOddTurn) {
                        try {
                            object.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(counter);
                    counter += 2;
                    isOddTurn=Boolean.TRUE;
                    object.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am failing to understand in all three cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Local Boolean

The problem with the second code is that each Thread has its own `Boolean` variable. This may be initialized with the same instance but if one thread changes its own variable, the other thread will not *see* that changed on its variable.

Basically:

```
class OddPrinter implements Runnable {
    private Boolean isOddTurn; // (1)
    ...
    public void run() {
        ...
        isOddTurn = FALSE:  // changing only (1) (setting different instance)
        ...
}

class EvenPrinter implements Runnable {
    private Boolean isOddTurn; // (2)
    ...
    public void run() {
        ...
        while (isOddTurn) {  // checking only (2), but (1) is changed by OddPrinter
        ...
}
```

---

###### AtomicBoolean

The first code is working since both threads are getting the same instance of `AtomicBoolean` and *only* changing its state `itsOddTurn.set(...)`, not assigning a new instance to the variable. So each thread is able to *see* the changes made by the other thread.

---

###### Global Boolean

The third code, despite using `Boolean` as the first, is working since there is only one (global) variable being used to save the flag. So each thread is able to *see* the new instance assigned by the other thread.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the immutability of the `Boolean` class and how references are handled between the `OddPrinter` and `EvenPrinter` in your second snippet. When you pass `isOddTurn` to c'tor of `OddPrinter` and `EvenPrinter`, each one receives its own copy of the reference to the `Boolean` object. When you later update `isOddTurn`, you are actually creating a new `Boolean` object and updating the reference in the current class, but the other class still holds the old reference, so the change is not visible. This does not happen when you use `AtomicBoolean`.

> If I make the isOddTurn variable as global Boolean instead of using it as instance variable in both threads, then it works fine.

In case of global (class-level) variable, a single reference to the `Boolean` object is shared among all instances of the `OddPrinter` and `EvenPrinter` classes. When one thread updates the value of `isOddTurn`, the change is visible to the other thread because they are both referencing the same object.

Comment: Using isOddTurn as global volatile Boolean doesn't work , see the gist . Why is that . 
https://gist.github.com/Abhi-Codes/b34cd9b9e7c7b568c07b6bfff79c7b2b

Comment: Reworked the answer.

Comment: The fact that `Boolean` objects are immutable is not a problem. The problem depends on whether or not the threads share the thing that they modify. Example 1 works because they modify the same, shared `AtomicBoolean` instance. Example 3 works, _despite the immutability of `Boolean`,_ because they modify the same, shared, class-level `Boolean` variable. Example 2 doesn't work because each thread modifies its own private variable.